# Reading Sharepoint user profiles in Office365 using REST API on behalf of an application - Error 500

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365, azure-active-directory

I am trying to read sharepoint user profiles using REST Api on userprofiles.peoplemanager Service.
We defined an application in azure AD, with "Sharepoint: read user profiles" permission for both application and on behalf of a user.

- When i request the service on behalf of a user (for example getpropertiesfor(@v) with any user identifier passed as parameter), everything is working fine.
- When i execute the exact same request on behalf of the application, i'm getting a HTTP 500 error.

Am i doing something wrong ?
What am i supposed to be allowed to execute on behalf of an application with the Azure AD permission "Sharepoint: read user profiles" ?

Comment: Make sure you set the proper permissions for your app to read user profile for the app permissions. Here is a list of permissions for SP service apps permissions in Azure AD & o365: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/application-manifest#AppManifest_SharePointScopes

Comment: I have set all the *.Read.All SharePoint permissions for service apps, including of course User.Read.All (Allows the app to read user profiles without a signed in user.)